# Interface property depend on other property

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the next interface:

```
interface TestInterface {
  id?: string;
  type?: string;
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite in a way that when I perform a check that *id !== undefined* it'll automatically mean that *type* property is also defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mimic this with union types.

**Simple example:**

```js
interface INonNullable {
    id: string;
    type: string;
}
interface INullable {
    id?: undefined;
    type?: undefined;
}
type FinalType = INonNullable | INullable;

function testId(x: FinalType) 
{
  if (x.id !== undefined) {
    x.type // string
  }
}
```

`FinalType` is optional, you can simply use `(x: INonNullable | INullable)` everywhere.

**Add type-guard function:**

You can also make function with type guard to test for your criteria and narrow the type that way:

```
interface INonNullable {
    id: string;
    type: string;
}
interface INullable {
    id?: undefined;
    type?: undefined;
}
type FinalType = INonNullable | INullable;

function isNonNullable(x: FinalType): x is INonNullable
{
  return x.id !== undefined;
}

let x = {};

if (isNonNullable(x)) {
  x.type // string;
}
```

You have more info about this in Typescript documentation:
[User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

**Reusable `Empty<T>`:**

Another neat option, as mentioned in the comment by Patrick Roberts, to make more re-usable solution using mapped types and generics:

```js
interface INonNullable {
    id: string;
    type: string;
}
type Empty<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: undefined;
}
type FinalType<T> = T | Empty<T>;

function testId(x: FinalType<INonNullable>) {
  if (x.id !== undefined) {
    x.type // string
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. For a more generic approach, you could even define a generic type [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gJLmvJZAbwFgAoZS5YAEwC5kspQBzAbnKuTAE8AHCAyasOZAL7lyvAcgCiAWz68APKgB8yALzFOyANoBpaiGQBrCDwD2MNAF0A-AwCuIGhBigINUWNFT+KABioHAANqgBWmiYOHiwiCgAPnKKKuhYuJDxSGp+ZDAuCGDAliaQGTQAFAAeDMEgYRECAJQ6FNQ2NQB0tMgAhJraLm4eIF6tpO2U1V3SKAD084xgzCAsuhLiQA).

Answer (score 1):

Lets see your example:

```
interface TestInterface {
  id?: string;
  type?: string;
}

const objectForTest: TestInterface = {
  id: '12345',
  type: 'some type'
}
```

You can do it in the following ways:

1) `objectForTest?.id`

If this operator meet `undefined`, it will return this value without throwing a `TypeError`.

This is equvalent to:

```
const testValue = (objectForTest === null || objectForTest === undefined) ?
    undefined 
    :
    objectForTest.id;
```

2) `objectForTest!.id`

In this case you say to type checker: "Hey, I promise you that `objectForTest` is not `null` or `undefined`".

Answer (score 1):

Here a way to do what you want, using union :

```
interface IdWithType {
  id: string;
  type: string;
}

interface WithoutId {
  id?: never;
  type?: string;
}

type TestInterface = IdWithType | WithoutId

// You cannot instansiate an object of type TestInterface with an id and with out a type

const yo: TestInterface = { // Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TestInterface'.
  id: "hey"
}


const testFunction = (a: TestInterface) => {
  if (a.id) {
    const b = a.type // string
  }
  const c = a.type // string | undefined
}
```